# Need help with query

Tags: sql

I have the following table. It stores messages that each user has sent and received in chats.  I want to select all the messages that a user has sent and received and retrieve them. I can then sort them by their conversation id in JQUERY. Would I have to do two queries for this or can I embed a query? Essentially what I want to do is

```
SELECT * FROM chatbox WHERE sender=? 
and 
SELECT * FROM chatbox WHERE receiver=?
```

I just want to try to avoid having two queries and two while loops for the results. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  chatbox
WHERE
  sender=? or receiver=?
```

Comment: I didn't know there was an OR haha. Nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Scarface - Are you familar with `ORDER BY` for the "sort them by their conversation id" requirement?

Comment: @Scarface - Martin has a point - instead of sorting them in JQuery, you can have them sorted inside the query with ORDER BY clause.

Comment: When I meant sort, I meant just have each comment based on its conversation id sent to its appropriate chatbox. They are not in sequential order. The id is a random sequence generated for each conversation so that I can allocate the comments appropriately to each converation (all comments in a conversation share same id).

Comment: $('#chatbox[data-convo_id="'+json[i].convo_id+'"]>#messagebox').prepend

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, and also do the ordering with MySQL too:

```
SELECT *
FROM chatbox
WHERE
  sender="<id>" OR
  receiver="<id>"
ORDER BY conversation_id
```

Comment: When I meant sort, I meant just have each comment based on its conversation id sent to its appropriate chatbox. They are not in sequential order. The id is a random sequence generated for each conversation so that I can allocate the comments appropriately to each converation (all comments in a conversation share same id). Thanks though Alex.

Comment: $('#chatbox[data-convo_id="'+json[i].convo_id+'"]>#messagebox').prepend

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single query along with the sorting;

```
SELECT * FROM chatbox WHERE 'username' IN (sender, receiver) ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Why would I use IN instead of OR and =? Is there some sort of efficiency to doing so?

Comment: No advantage both are just as good, I just think its more readable

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM chatbox WHERE sender=? OR receiver=?
```